# Open search dialog with a selected word with VBA MS-Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've joined these methods to create a macro to be assigned to a right-click menu button. The objective is to select the word under the cursor with the right-click, click on the macro, which selects that word (trimming spaces) and sends it to the default search-dialog of Word.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateMacro()
    Dim MenuButton As CommandBarButton
    With CommandBars("Text")
        Set MenuButton = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
        With MenuButton
            .Caption = "Find word"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "FindWordUnderCursor"
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub ResetRightClick()
    Application.CommandBars("Text").Reset
End Sub

Sub FindWordUnderCursor()
    Dim pos As Long
    Dim myRange As Range

    '~~> if the cursor is at the end of the word
    Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

    Do While Len(Trim(Selection.Text)) = 0
        '~~> Move one character behind so that the cursor is
        '~~> at the begining or in the middle
        Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
    Loop

    '~~> Expand to get the word
    Selection.Expand Unit:=wdWord
    If Selection.Characters(Selection.Characters.Count) = " " Then
        Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
    End If

    '~~> Display the word
    Debug.Print Selection.Text

End Sub
```

The only thing left to achieve is that the selected word puts itself in the default MS-Word search dialog box (or open it if it's not active), which automatically highlights all the occurrences in the document. Of course, if I right-click another word and select the macro, the new word has to substitute the previous one. Can you help, please?

Here are the two desired steps:

[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hZfg.jpg)
[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcw9F.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to fill the search field in the navigation pane using the Word object model. However, you are able to highlight all occurrences of a word easily using a single line of code:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.HitHighlight Selection.Range.Text
```

As an alternative to filling the search box in the navigation pane, you may open the search dialog box (but you won't get the immediate highlight of text):

```
Dim dlg As Dialog
Set dlg = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditFind)
dlg.Find = Selection.Range.Text
dlg.Display
```

Comment: The single line of code does the trick, and I can get rid of the highlight just "undoing" the action. Of course the whole method is not perfect (I wish Word had it built-in to help writers to find duplications. I'm using this along with another macro I've written to identify the repeated words in a text, if you wish to check it in my questions you're welcome.

Comment: Oops, I've noticed that if I select Undo, this action undoes the highlight but also the previous action performed. That is, if I corrected one word and hit undo, the highlight goes but the correction reverts. Any idea to circumvent this?

Comment: Oh, never mind, the highlight disappears if I hit one single space anywhere.